# Adding Pagination using PagedList.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I have an Index Razor View (MVC5 C#), that simply displays a list of data from a table called ICS_Supplies.  This is fine, except there are many rows of data and therefore, it can take a long time to populate the view.  Thus, the need for Pagination.  I come from old asp.net forms with VB.net, where pagination is quite simple.  MVC5 and C# are still quite new . . and I am having a problem getting it working.

Here is where I am at.  My Model:

```
namespace ICS20web.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using PagedList;


public partial class ICS_Supplies
{
    [Key]
    public int Supplies_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Old_ItemID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    public int? OnHand { get; set; }

    public int? ReorderLevel { get; set; }

    public int? ReorderAmt { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string UnitMeasure { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string SupplyLocation { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string InvType { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Discontinued { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my Controller for Index

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ICS20web.Models;
using PagedList;

namespace ICS20web.Controllers
{
public class SuppliesController : Controller
{
    private ICS_Internal_Transactions db = new ICS_Internal_Transactions();

    // GET: Supplies
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies.OrderByDescending(g =>     g.Supplies_ID).ToList();
        var model = new PagedList<ICS_Supplies>(supplies, 1, 10);

        return View(model);


    }
```

And here is my View Code

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ICS20web.Models.ICS_Supplies>
@using PagedList.Mvc;


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Old_ItemID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemDescription)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OnHand)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReorderLevel)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReorderAmt)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitMeasure)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupplyLocation)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InvType)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Discontinued)
    </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Old_ItemID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemDescription)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OnHand)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReorderLevel)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReorderAmt)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitMeasure)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplyLocation)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discontinued)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Supplies_ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Supplies_ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Supplies_ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, pagesize = 5 }))
```

I have installed PagedList.MVC Nuget and added the appropriate references in my View Web.Config file, as instructed.

I am currently getting the following error when the page tries to load:

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'IPagedList' does not contain a definition for 'Old_ItemID' and no extension method 'Old_ItemID' accepting a first argument of type 'IPagedList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

First thing I did, was remove the object 'Old_ItemID' from the view, but then the same error generates with the next object.

I am trying to follow through the error.  Looks like it's telling me that there is no definition for 'Old_ItemID' in IPagedLIST, however when I look at the model ICS_Supplies, the definition is there.  Did I set it up wrong in the controller?  I am lost as to where to look next.

Comment: A nuget package for pagination is a tremendous overkill. You just need to add an ‘int Page’ to your model and then use that value in your index controller (through routing) to take the selected portion of data from your db using ‘db.ICS_Supplies.Skip(n * Page).Take(n)’, where ‘n’ is the number of items per page.

Comment: Your table header row references the model (`IPagedList`) as if it had properties of `ICS_Supplies`.

Comment: @Jasen - BINGO!  Thank you.  Your comment was all that was needed to get this working properly.